# Tradingview: You're at maximum indicator-ness. How exactly does it work?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

> You're at maximum indicator-ness. Premium plans have a limit of 24 indicators-on-indicators per chart layout... and you've hit it.
> Basic 1 Pro 1 Pro+ 9 Premium 24

The error message occurred as I wanted to add an EMA clicking on my script *"Add indicator/strategy on CCI"* on top of my chart that has also only 6 plots. My script uses only 2 indicators, the `ta.cci` smoothened by a `ta.ema` and that's it.
Where the message probably comes from relates to the fact that the cci-ema process in my script comes from a library that has many other indicators, although none of them is actually being used here, meaning: none of them appears in my `export getCCI()` function that is invoked in my script. So I'd say I have 2 indicators on chart. Confirming this I can add the `ta.ema` in pine script manually without a problem.
Why does TradingView think I used up all 24?

Comment: Can you send a support ticket after the error appears? That will help to solve issue.